# Server video stream without reencoding on linux

Tags: linux, streaming, ffserver

I like to stream video from an H.264 providing camera. As it is already sufficiently compressed, I just need a server providing something like mpegts transport streams for raw tcp or http access.

Is this possible using for example ffmpeg, ffserver or other open source tools? ffserver seem to always force reencoding of the incoming media. ffmpeg alone can omit reencoding via the `-vcodec copy` option, but it only provides a single stream, only serving one client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used "-override_ffserver" within ffmpeg feed to ffserver, which preserves "-c copy" (thus, no re-encoding); otherwise, ffserver seems to dictate ffmpeg about encoding options. Hope this helps, I'm by no means a ff* power user.